# Dealing with partial derivatives in a function space

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analyticity

Please read the following details below.

[image]

---

**Question:** I want to show now that if $r>s>0,f \in F_s (\Omega), $ and $u \in F_r (\Omega)$, then for any $i$,

$$f \frac{\partial u}{\partial z_i} \in F_s(\Omega).$$

My work so far: This will follow if I can show that $\partial u / \partial z_i \in F_s(\Omega).$ Since $u \in F_r (\Omega)$, $u$ must be analytic in $\Omega_r$ and  so $\partial u / \partial z_i$ must also be analytic in $\Omega_r$. Then at the very least, $\partial u / \partial z_i$ must be in $E_s(\Omega)$. But I have no idea how to show that $\partial u / \partial z_i$ is in $F_s(\Omega)$, or equivalently, that it is in the closure of $\mathscr{H}(\mathbb{C}^n)$ in $E_s(\Omega)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cauchy integral provides an estimate of the derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z_k}(w)$ of a holomorphic function depending on a bound on the absolute value of $f(z)$ on the (distinguished) boundary of a polydisk $P$ for $w$ in any smaller polydisk $P' \subset\mspace{-2mu}\subset P$. ($A \subset\mspace{-2mu}\subset B$ means that $A$ is relatively compact in $B$, the closure of $A$ is compact and contained in $B$.)

As a consequence of that, if $f_n$ are holomorphic functions converging to $g$ uniformly on an open set $U$, all partial derivatives (of all orders) of the $f_n$ converge to the corresponding partial derivative of $g$ **locally** uniformly on $U$.

Since for $0 < s < r$ you have $\Omega_s \subset\mspace{-2mu}\subset \Omega_r$, if $f_n \to u$ uniformly on $\Omega_r$, then $\frac{\partial f_n}{\partial z_i} \to \frac{\partial u}{\partial z_i}$ uniformly on $\Omega_t$ for all $t < r$.

Since partial derivatives of entire functions are entire, you have

$$u \in F_r(\Omega) \Rightarrow \frac{\partial u}{\partial z_i} \in F_s(\Omega),\quad 0 < s < r.$$

Comment: Thanks! One important fact that I forgot is that $f_n \to u$ in the supremum norm implies that $f_n \to u$ uniformly.